# How to make a Java GUI panel component sleep?

Tags: java, swing

Lets say i have 2 GUI panels A and B

In Panel A, I have a jTextArea that you can input a String ,
and a jbutton that if it is pressed, it appends the String inside a jTextArrea on a jTextField that is inside Panel B

What i want to do is make the String append on Panel B after waiting 2 seconds
without having the Thread Going on to Sleep

It has to be able to input another string into jTextArea during the wait period

How do i do this without using Thread.sleep()?

Comment: Either use a Swing `Timer` or a `SwingWorker`

Comment: how?  do i do that ? @MadProgrammer

Comment: You could start by having a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Answer (score 1):

Start by taking a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to understand the issues and the possible solutions.

If you really don't want to use `Thread#sleep` (which you could use with a `SwingWorker`), a Swing `Timer` is probably the best solution.  It allows you to setup a callback after a given delay (you can also repeat the callback, but in this case, we only need it once).

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField field;
        private JTextArea ta1;
        private JTextArea ta2;
        private JButton btn;

        private Timer timer;

        public TestPane() {
            JPanel panelA = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel panelB = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

            setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));

            add(panelA);
            add(panelB);

            field = new JTextField(10);
            ta1 = new JTextArea(10, 20);
            ta1.setEditable(false);
            btn = new JButton("Add");

            panelA.add(field, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            panelA.add(new JScrollPane(ta1));
            panelA.add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            ta2 = new JTextArea(10, 20);
            ta2.setEditable(false);
            panelB.add(new JScrollPane(ta2));

            ActionListener startListener = new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    ta1.append(field.getText() + "\n");
                    if (!timer.isRunning()) {
                        field.setEnabled(false);
                        btn.setEnabled(false);
                        timer.start();
                    }
                }
            };

            field.addActionListener(startListener);
            btn.addActionListener(startListener);

            timer = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    ta2.append(field.getText() + "\n");
                    field.setEnabled(true);
                    btn.setEnabled(true);
                    field.setText(null);
                    field.requestFocusInWindow();
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(false);
        }

    }

}
```